# Bulk renaming files based on directory's name

Tags: linux

I have a relatively large number of files that are organized as below:

```
Control/Subject1/extra/filename.bvec
Control/Subject2/extra/filename.bvec
Control/Subject3/extra/filename.bvec
```

I am trying to rename the `filename.bvecs` so that they have their subject ID prefixed to their `.bvec` filename (`Subject1_filename.bvec`, etc..)

I know that I can use the code below using the directory that `filename.bvec` is in, but I can't seem to manipulate it to use the subject ID's.

```
for extra in *; do mv $extra/filename.bvec $extra_filename.txt; done;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Prepare simulation:

```
$ for i in `seq 1 3`; do mkdir -p Control/Subject${i}/extra/; touch Control/Subject${i}/extra/filename.bvec; done
$ tree
.
└── Control
    ├── Subject1
    │   └── extra
    │       └── filename.bvec
    ├── Subject2
    │   └── extra
    │       └── filename.bvec
    └── Subject3
        └── extra
            └── filename.bvec

7 directories, 3 files
```

Do the job:

```
$ for i in `find . -type f`; do nn=`sed 's,.*/\([^/]\+\)/extra/.*,\1,' <<<$i`; echo "$i -> $nn"; mv $i `dirname $i`/${nn}`basename $i`; done
./Control/Subject3/extra/filename.bvec -> Subject3
./Control/Subject2/extra/filename.bvec -> Subject2
./Control/Subject1/extra/filename.bvec -> Subject1
```

Checking results:

```
$ tree
.
└── Control
    ├── Subject1
    │   └── extra
    │       └── Subject1filename.bvec
    ├── Subject2
    │   └── extra
    │       └── Subject2filename.bvec
    └── Subject3
        └── extra
            └── Subject3filename.bvec

7 directories, 3 files
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: a splendid simulation! I wish more people thought graphically ;-) . Good luck to all.

Comment: Backticks are less splendid ;) Hey, it's 2016 now, think using `$( )` instead

Answer (score 1):

With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and recursion, the re-usable way :

```
$ shopt -s globstar # enable recursion with **
$ rename -n 's!Control/(Subject\d+)/extra/filename\.bvec!Control/$1/extra/${1}_filename.bvec!' **
```

#### Output:

```
Control/Subject1/extra/filename.bvec -> Control/Subject1/extra/Subject1_filename.bvec
Control/Subject2/extra/filename.bvec -> Control/Subject2/extra/Subject2_filename.bvec
Control/Subject3/extra/filename.bvec -> Control/Subject3/extra/Subject3_filename.bvec
```

#### Note

(remove -n switch when your tests are OK)

[image: warning]
 **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

and not containing:

```
ELF
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: I would say this (`rename` written in Perl) is the _other_ tool... you need to find and install additionally. Usually `rename` comes from `util-linux` package which is definitely a very base package, installed (almost?) in all distributions even in minimal configuration.